# In Android, can I have different activities use the same class file?

Tags: android, class, android-activity

I was wondering if it's possible in Android to declare different activities (say `.ActivityA` and `.ActivityB`) in AndroidManifest and use the same class file.

Is this achievable somehow?

One possible solution is a base class and then create other class files which inherit from that base class. But is there any other way than to have multiple class files?

I mean, the code should be almost identical for both activities I need this for. A couple of `ifs` here and there might be needed depending on the activity being called though.

How would you solve this problem?

**[EDIT]**

Judging by the responses I don't think I made myself clear enough, sorry about that. **But I explicitly need to have different activities.** Not a single one passing different values through Intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One possible solution is a base class and then create other class
> files which inherit from that base class.

- This is best implementation.

> A couple of ifs here and there might be needed depending on the
> activity being called though.

- Consider [State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) Pattern.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the State pattern and what exactly is the benefit on my situation (maybe I really didn't get it's purpose).

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want to access the Activity. Are you creating different Activity subclasses depending on some logic from within your application? Do they need to respond to different Intents from outside your application? If the first case, you could likely easily reuse a single Activity class and pass the conditional information (the stuff you're looking at for the `ifs` here and there) in the Bundle you pass through the Intent. Otherwise, you're probably best suited creating separate Activity subclasses in their own files.

Why the focus on multiple classes per file?

Comment: I explicitly need to have different activities (updated my question). I'm sorry but I don't understand your last question...

Comment: You say you need different explicit activities but you haven't said why it's so important to have them "in the same class file".

Comment: Because the code is basically the same and I don't want to repeat it across different files. The common solution for that is a base class and extend my activities from that one but I was just wondering if there was another way that would allow me to declare 2 activities for the same class file. Maybe with some "trick" on the manifest or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `abstract class CommonActivity extends Activity` with common functions, and both activities A and B will extends this one. In manifest you have to mention A and B, without common one.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean, the code should be almost identical for both activities I need this for. A couple of ifs here and there might be needed depending on the activity being called though.

If their is only few changes needed that too based on what and how you are calling, then use same Activity class by passing a value to it using Intent. Suppose you are calling "CommonActivity" for type "A", then while calling "CommonActivity" use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CommonActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("calledForType", "A");
```

In your CommonActivity :

```
String calledForType = "";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ......
  calledForType = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("calledForType");
  calledForType = calledForType.toUpper();   // Better for comparing later 
}
```

Now, wherever you have to handle the differnces with if's use :

```
if (calledForType.equals("A")) {
     // Do This For A
} else if (calledForType.equals("B")) {
    // Do this for B
}

// Do this for common
```

This way, you can handle out for N number of activities.

Comment: I explicitly need to have different activities (updated my question).

Comment: @RicardoAmaral, if you need to have differnt activities, then what's the problem of. Best option is to go with BaseActivity and extend it your Activies. for almost - all similarities. Include only required in ActivityA, .... class.

Comment: It's not a problem per se but I don't know all the possibilities the Android framework provides to developers and I decided to ask if there was a better/simpler way. That's all.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral, no problem dear. For base activity, implement its onCreate() and all common things that you other activities need at start up and in your Activity call super.onCreate(..) accordingly - not necesary it should be the 1st line. In my 1 case, I use same xml file for many activities. So in BaseActivity have setcontentView &  got buttons using findViewById. But have added listener for the buttons in other Activity.

Comment: I also overidden onDestroy in BaseActivity and call a private method to clean up components. When I call activity.finish(), my BaseActivity is also finished and thus is onDestroy called automatically. I guess this gives you some idea about how to implement both of them. If you still need guidance, feel free.